# How to convert RGB matrix to binary array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code to convert image(jpg) to binary using Matlab for bidirectional visible light communication. there are some mistakes. I need to create RGB matrices and save binary values in an array using a nested loop. after that, I need to send binary values for the LED driver. I did some coding parts. can you help me to do this?

```matlab
i=imread('imageName.jpg');

R = i(:,:,1); %red 

G = i(:,:,2); %green  

B = i(:,:,3); %blue

for i=1:183

    for j=1:275

        R(i,j);

        binStr = dec2bin(R(i,j));
    
    end
end
```

Comment: You're overwriting `binStr` each time through the loop. You'll need to preallocate an array of the proper size and write to the proper array element on each iteration. Also, `R(i,j);` does nothing. If you're using it for debugging, it would be better to use the built-in debugger and step through each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Also, depending on the ordering you want, you may be able to accomplish this in one line.